# pass a variable from a servlet to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I develop a system of voting star base, when the user vote, I am sending an ajax request to my servlet that puts the database update

here is my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            contentType: "charset=utf-8",
            url:''+encodeURI('/RecommandationDefault/rating?track='+surat+'&recitateur='+recitateur+'&vote='+voteVal),
            success:function(resp){
                alert(response);
            }


        });
```

and here is the code of my servlet

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String n1=new String(request.getParameter("track").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("track"+n1);
                String n2=request.getParameter("recitateur");
        String n3=request.getParameter("vote");
        try {
            DaoLastfm D = new DaoLastfm();
            D.insert_vote(n2, n1, n3);
            // processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(rating.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

the insertion works flawlessly,

My concern is how after insertion into the database, the servlet forwards to my javascript content in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just print the variable to the response in the servlet:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(variable);
```

And fix the misspelling in your Ajax success method, by deciding whether you want the variable to be called resp or response:

```
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
```